Disabling or Bypassing Dolby Atmos Processing on Android
When using android.media.MediaPlayer, is it possible to configure it so that the audio bypasses the Dolby Atmos, or any other effects/quality processing for that matter?
This seems to be a standard feature on Samsung devices (the only brand I own) but possibly other brands.
The audio that this app plays (often not music nor speech) is already processed to sound like it is suppose to.  But when Dolby Atmos is enabled in the settings, and this seems to be the default, it adds a terrible quality to the sound.  I could instruct the user to disable this setting, but A) that is cumbersome, B) it disables it for the whole system, and C) there are reports that the setting turns itself back on from time to time.
So, I would prefer a way to configure the audio bus to skip it altogether just for my stream.
I have attempted to set the AudioAttributes to CONTENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN and disabling spatialization, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.  I even tried the CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC, CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH, CONTENT_TYPE_MOVIE values (which happen to correspond to the several types you can choose in the Atmos settings other than auto) and it doesn't seem to make any difference.
Another thought was whether the system would honor some metadata embedded in the media file (e.g. HLS, mp3, ogg, aac, etc) that says not to process it.  Only, I'm not aware of any such metadata.
Any ideas?  TIA

I suspect there isn't anything you can do about it.  Even if you do, I don't know of any smartphone in the last decade that has reasonable unprocessed audio.  They all do dynamic compression at least.  And then, there are all the Bluetooth headphones that also have DSP.  Maybe if your content was Atmos encoded, you'd at least have more control over how it was rendered?
